# Replacing values in standard fields

Tags: picklist, customization

Is it possible to have only 4 values in type picklist field of account. I am trying to replace this values but not sure how to do it.

Similar is the case for Industry picklist on account object

Comment: Setup > Account > Fields > Type > `Edit | Del`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, go to Customize->Account->Fields and then click the Field Label:

[image]

Which then allows you to edit on this screen:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Phil... I was just using edit or replace which was not serving my purpose... I had to drill down on Type field to have this values.. Thannks a lottt

Comment: No problem @NonProfitOrgDeveloper :)